# From a COM Service EXE gets started

Tags: c++, service, com, atl

I'm trying to program my first COM Service EXE. And I'm can't to find some informations in the Net.

A Service EXE starts executing from its `Run()` method, do I need to implement my main functions in it to get my service works or do I need to implement a specific function that is related to it?

Thank you so much !!

Comment: Is serving up COM objects the main point of this service? If so, may I recommend implementing it an in-proc COM server (i. e. a DLL) and running it within COM+? It's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated that you are using C++ and ATL, but it can be guessed from the tags given to the question.

If your COM objects do not need any global initialization, you do not have to modify the provided Run() function or anything similar. It works like this: If the service is not running, and some program requires a COM object from your service be created, the COM/DCOM infrastructure first starts the service. Alternatively, you can pre-start the service using any standard means (e.g. manually, or set its startup type to Automatic). Once the service is running, the COM objects are created within the service.

So, without a need for extra global initialization, you simply implement your COM objects as in any local server or in-process server. If they need any instance initialization, you will put it into the constructor of the COM object, or to its FinalConstruct method (this method gets called after the constructor, so you have take advantage of the fact that the object already exists, AND you can also fail it if needed, as FinalConstruct returns an HRESULT).

If you need a global (service-wide) initialization code, then you can put it into several places, each at different stage of the service construction. One of such places would be the Run() method, yes.

Comment: Sorry if I've mentionned enough informations. In fact, I'm trying to build a Service EXE using ATL. This service needs to Run at the start of the computer and runs its main processes in loop. Will I then simply need to implement my main process into the Run() method? I couldn't understand your explanation about `FinalConstruct method` and the `constructor of a COM object`. Where do I locate them? Or, how do I to add them?

Comment: It looks like you have chosen to implement a Windows service using the "ATL Project" Wizard, but that you actually have no need to implement any COM objects (somewhat contrary to the original question). This needs to be clarified before an answer can be given.